# 10 friends of a triangular baseball batter

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, visual, crosswords

[image]

---

1. "I'll do it tomorrow"
2. "Lattices and nets are my forte"
3. The paved one
4. A shadowy character
5. A place where organic and inorganic meet
6. Older brother of a piece of text
7. A job title. Do not confuse with a concept!
8. A fancy device
9. Many observed events, sometimes unbelievable
10. The one who gets things done

---

*Thick line indicates where word 1 ends*

Comment: FYI, I'm intrigued by this one. I believe I have 1, 3, 9, 10, and maybe 5. No clue on 2, 4, 6, 7, 8...